# About long long and long double

Tags: c++, long-integer, standards, primitive-types

Since when have they been part of standard C++? I think `long long` is a C++0x feature, is that right? What about `long double`? Was that already in C++98 or C++03?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `long double` and `long long` have been around for quite a while, and were standardised in C89 and C99, respectively. C++ standardised `long double` from its first version, C++98, and will add `long long` in the upcoming revision to the standard.

Comment: I believe you're correct. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#C99

Comment: Just to clarify, `long double` is C++98 and `long long` is C++0x, correct or wrong?

Comment: Not downvoted since the question was about C++ anyway, but `long double` is not new to C99. [Multiple sources](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/219940-long-double-c89)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out MSalters; I placed too much trust in Wikipedia. Emended.